# Fastest way to read last line within pattern of multiple files with the same extension

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing, scripting

I have in a directory `/home/files/` some files that all have the same extension `.txt`.

For example

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
test.txt
```

These files are all the same in data format but the data are different.
All these files have at least the following line inside

```
frames=[number here]
```

This line appears multiple times in a file so i need to get the value of `frames=` that appears last in the file.

And as i stated i want to get that line, from all the above files that match the extension .txt in a directory (no need for recursive).

Is there any single bash command to do that?

### EDIT

Expected output:

```
1.txt=5000
2.txt=123
3.txt=3452
4.txt=111
5.txt=958
test.txt=1231
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `find` + `grep`:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'grep -HPo "frames=\K.*" "$0" | tail -n1' {} \;
```

And with shell `for` loop + `grep` in similar fashion:

```
for file in *.txt; do grep -HPo 'frames=\K.*' "$file" | tail -n1; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk` and provided that there will only be one `=` on the line, you can do:

```
gawk -F= 'ENDFILE { print FILENAME"="$2 }' *.txt
```

#### Update

Just realised I misread this question, I thought the line you were looking for was always be the last line. To use the last line that starts with `frames=`, for `gawk` do:

```
gawk -F= '/^frames=/ { frames=$2 } ENDFILE { print FILENAME"="frames }' *.txt
```

Or with any `awk`:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  awk -F= '/^frames=/ { frames=$2 } END { print FILENAME"="frames }' "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `awk`

```
awk -F= '/^frame/{line=FILENAME "=" $2}NR!=1 && FNR==1{print line}END{print line}' *.txt
```

Or with `sed` (GNU version more than 4.2.2)

```
sed -sn '/^frame/{s///;h};${F;x;p}' *.txt | sed 'N;s/\n//'
```

Comment: @mikeserv Please extend your offer re `F` in `sed` (example?). I add `bash` as extra (main is `awk`) and I am not sure that is a slowest but may be longest.

Answer (score 1):

With `pax` *(probably also most any `tar`)* and `tr` and GNU `sed`:

```
pax -w ./*txt | 
tr -s \\0     | 
sed -nz '/txt$/h
         /\n*.*frames\(=[0-9]*\).*\n/!d
    H;x;s//\1/p'
```